# The automation rule fired when an update is made does not lead to the correct execution of the code

Tags: jira, atlassian-sourcetree, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I am using an automation rule and I have used issue updated as an automation trigger for my rule and it's not working, I receive the message, the issue does not have any components even though the issue does have components.

You can see it in these screenshots:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
Here is the code which is supposed to be executed based on an issue update. I printed the issue and I have gotten the following: =====MOUNA CAMELIA ISSUE:::: SF-437 ISSUE COMPONENTS []

The issue components are empty which is obviosuly wrong. My issue does have components.

```
package SuperFeature

import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue

import org.apache.log4j.Logger

import com.atlassian.jira.project.version.Version

import com.atlassian.jira.bc.project.component.ProjectComponent

import com.atlassian.jira.bc.project.component.ProjectComponentManager

import com.atlassian.jira.security.JiraAuthenticationContext

import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor

import com.atlassian.jira.issue.label.LabelManager

    

def log = Logger.getLogger('atlassian-jira.log')

List < String > componentList = new ArrayList < String > ()

List < ProjectComponent > finalComponentList = new ArrayList < ProjectComponent > ()

def projectNames = [ 'WF', 'BF', 'EF', 'YF', 'CLTF']

log.warn("=====MOUNA CAMELIA ISSUE:::: "+ issue +" ISSUE COMPONENTS "+issue.getComponents())

if (issue.getComponents().size() == 0) {

    issue.update {

         String text = "Issue does not have any components\n"

        setCustomFieldValue('Execution Summary', text )

    }

} else if (issue.getFixVersions().size() == 0) {

    issue.update {

        String text = "Issue does not have any fix versions\n"

        setCustomFieldValue('Execution Summary', text)

    }

} else {

    int componentSize = issue.getComponents().size()

   

    int generatedIssuesCounter= 0

     for (ProjectComponent component: issue.getComponents()) {

                      String componentName = component.getName()

                    def shortenedComponentName = componentName.substring(componentName.indexOf("-") + 1)

                    def projectName = componentName.substring(0, componentName.indexOf("-"))

                

                        

                        if(projectNames.contains(projectName)){

                        

                        

                        def newIssueproject = ComponentAccessor.projectManager.getProjectObjByKey(projectName)

                        //log.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA found--"+found+"--NEW LIST SIZE: "+newList)

                        List < ProjectComponent > newList = new ArrayList < > (newIssueproject.getComponents());

                        def found = newList.any {

                            it.getName().equals(shortenedComponentName)

                        }

                        if (found) {

                            componentList.add(componentName+" ===> WILL BE GENERATED")

                            finalComponentList.add(component)

                            generatedIssuesCounter++

                        } else{

                            componentList.add(componentName+" ===> CANNOT BE GENERATED")

                        }

                        }

            

     }

     

    issue.update {

        String text = "The super feature " + issue + " will be split into " + generatedIssuesCounter + " features, one for each component:\n"

        

       text = text + componentList.join("\n")    ;

         // Partition a list into list of lists size 3

       

        setCustomFieldValue('Execution Summary', text)

    }

}
```